# is choosing first value possible, for the primary key autoincrement column in sqlite3 using python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

I wrote a python3 scrypt, created a table using sqlite3 and set a primary key autoincrement, and it works. But i'd need to start autoincrement from a different number (default of course is '1'). (for example first row '2011',second row '2012',third row '2013',exc.....)  is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do that? Purpose of autoincrement is to create row identificator, what is the unique value for each row. According to [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

*The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and **should be avoided if not strictly needed**. It is usually not needed.*

If you want table where autoincrement will start at 2011 you should definetly avoid using **AUTOINCREMENT** column.

But I have another solution:

You should create table **without** autoincrement column.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
     col1 TEXT
    ,col2 INT
)
```

Then you create a **VIEW**:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_my_table
  AS
SELECT
    ROWID + 2010 as ID
    ,col1
    ,col2
FROM 
    my_table
```

To access the table data you will use view instead of table.

```sql
SELECT * FROM v_my_table
```

This **VIEW** will containt your autoincrement column started at 2011.